# How to connect to freeswitch remote database?

Tags: mysql, lua, odbc, voip, freeswitch

I have been trying to figure out if there is any way to connect to remote Database with FreeSwitch API.

FreeSwitch Lua API accepts only: Database name, username & password.

So it establishes the connection to localhost only.

```
local dbh = freeswitch.Dbh("odbc://my_db:uname:passwd") -- connect to ODBC database '
```

There is no option to provide host name if in case I want to make use of remote database server.

Is there any way ?

API Ref: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+with+Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using connect database using an ODBC DSN.

DB connect line in freeswitch

```
    freeswitch.Dbh("odbc://ODBC_DSN:DB_USERNAME:DB_PASSWD");
```

ODBC configuration file(in my system it's on `/etc/odbc.ini` this path)

```
[ODBC_DSN]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so
SERVER = #DB_HOST#
PORT = #DB_PORT#
DATABASE = #DB_NAME#
USERNAME = #DB_USER_NAME#
PASSWORD = #DB_PASSWORD#
OPTION = 67108864
Socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Reference link: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6586653

Hope this helps you.